# How to count ? values in a specific column using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am a very beginner of python and pandas.
My dataset has ? , which is not NaN or null.
I want to count how many ? are on certain columns.

I tried to use count value_counts() or other count functions but it did not work.
I want to count how many ? there are in workclass column. Thanks

[image]

I would like to know the way without using scikitlearn or other ML library.

Comment: for some reason i can't view your image

Comment: I edited but the table(image) does not show missing value(?).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `isin` function for this.
Here is an example.

```
arr = {'col1': ['?',2,'?',4], 'col2': [6,7,8,9]}
df = pd.DataFrame(arr)
df.isin(['?']).sum()
```

```
output:
col1    2
col2    0
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first task should be to replace all columns with `?` to `NaN` or `None` so that you can use built-in Pandas functions to easily count them.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'number': [1, 2, 3, 4, '?', 5],
        'string': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', '?', 'e']
       }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['number'] = df['number'].replace('?', np.NaN)
df['string'] = df['string'].replace('?', None)
```

Now you can count the number of missing values.

```
df.isna().sum()
```

Output:

```
number    1
string    1
dtype: int64
```